# Testing for C# vulnerabilities

Tags: c#, testing, functional-testing

I'm a tester in a company that uses Java for all its (web)applications. One of the first things I do when testing a new feature or build is using a ridiculously large numbers on input fields.

If the programmer was sloppy, I get a stacktrace on the screen or in the log. For me this is a quick way to get a first impression about the quality.

But now my company has purchased a web application which is programmed in C#. My question is, can I use the same method as I do on Java apps? Are there other ways to quickly bring a C# app to its knees?

Comment: Your input testing does not depend on language which was used for writing application. If there is no validation on field, application can always crash at business logic or data access layers

Comment: but the platform does make a difference...

Comment: @Weyland, it would be good to provide examples on what kind of difference that makes.

Comment: Why would you be testing a third party application?

Comment: "If the programmer was sloppy, I get a stacktrace on the screen or in the log" is the questioner's observation of Java web applications. Doesn't necessarily apply to a different platform. Sounds like an issue in itself actually.

Comment: @Weyland That indeed is my observation of Java web applications. But from your remark I get that is a incorrect observation? (I have very little expierence with C# web apps)

Comment: @paqogomez It's an application with a lot of configuration options and custom interfaces

Comment: My favorite: Get a 10 MB text file, open in a text editor (not Notepad), copy the text and paste it into all textboxes you can find. Usually makes applications ridiculously slow even on quad core machines, if not crash it. Don't know how well it works for web apps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about testing and as such will better fit to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If a programmer converts text into a numeric value, and he did not validate the data nor catch any exceptions, an exception may appear to the end user. This is also true for C#.

However keep in mind you're just poking at the software this way. The programmer in question may have tried out "bad input" and wrapped the whole thing in a `try { ... } catch {}` block that just ignores the exception.

If the test fails (exception details appear) you can quickly conclude that the software has input validation flaws, but if no exception details appear, the quality of the product may be just as bad.

Comment: seeing a stack trace in itself is a security vulnerbility

Comment: @WeylandYutani I can't quite place your comment to my answer. My intent was to remove explicit focus to a single test, not dive into a specific one. Also I'm not sure the OP is only interested in _security_ vulnerabilities.

Comment: oops i replied in the wrong place, sorry